# Can viruses break out of virtual machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, virus, gaming

There's this third party software called Gabb. It's designed for a particular game. Basically, what it does, it runs multiple instances of that game at the same time, allowing me to play multiple accounts at once.

I've read on many sources that it contains a virus that can leak out the game's account login info(username & password).

I have the option to run it in a virtual machine where my unimportant accounts are. My question is, can the virus still leak out of that virtual machine and leak out my main account's login info?

Comment: Your question is valid, but you'd be better off just finding something similar that isn't a virus. Why would it matter if you use a VM? The software would still just hijack the unimportant accounts as soon as you use them with the software (most likely), which would most likely cause them to get banned from the game depending on what the owner of the software decides to do to those accounts.

Comment: The only real answer is "maybe". It depends on sophistication of the attack, intent, exposed vectors such as shared folders, network cards, VT-d and so on. With direct access to a GPU or other devices there is potentially access vectors between host and guest that are not controlled or protected. It might be "safe" but there's no 100% absolute guarantee.